# Service Stop from mainActivity

Tags: android, service

I have a service that calls alarm manager in period time and I want to stop the service. I cancel only the alarm manager but my service was still running in the  background.

this is my code in Main Activity

```
start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
                showDialog(noInternetDialog);
            } else if (start.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(getResources().getString(R.string.start_interval))) {

                countLimit.setEnabled(false);
                timeLimit.setEnabled(false);

                start.setText(R.string.stop_interval);
                start.refreshDrawableState();

                // To save send configuration
                saveSendConfiguration();

                // Show sms to send
                XMLParser read = new XMLParser();
                String numberOfUnsend = read.getXmlFromUrl(baseURL + SMScount);
                status.setText(numberOfUnsend);

                Intent downloader = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
                downloader.putExtra("time", timeLimit.getSelectedItem()
                        .toString());
                downloader.putExtra("count", countLimit.getSelectedItem()
                        .toString());
                downloader.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
                        downloader, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

                int delay = Integer.parseInt(countLimit.getSelectedItem()
                        .toString());
                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        10 * 1000, delay * 60000, pendingIntent);
                Log.i(tag, "Call from main activity");
            } else {
                alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
                start.setText(R.string.start_interval);
                start.refreshDrawableState();
                countLimit.setEnabled(true);
                timeLimit.setEnabled(true);
                Log.i(tag, "Alarm Cancel");
            }

        }
    });
```

this is my alarm receiver code

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static String tag = "Saeed";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent update = new Intent(context, IntervalService.class);
    String time = intent.getStringExtra("time");
    String count = intent.getStringExtra("count");
    update.putExtra("time", time);
    update.putExtra("count", count);
    Log.i(tag, "Call service from Alaram Receiver," + time + "," + count);
    context.startService(update);
}

    }
```

and this is my service code

```
public class IntervalService extends IntentService {

private static final String tag = "Saeed";


private String baseURL;
private DatabaseHandler db;
private int time;
private int count;

private SharedPreferences pref;
ConnectionDetector cd;

public IntervalService() {
    super("Auto Interval");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.i(tag, "Interval Service implementation was run");
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.settings, false);
    pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    baseURL = pref.getString("baseUrl","");
    db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
    time = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("time"));
    count = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("count"));
    new Interval().execute(); //this is async task class
}
```

How can I stop service from my main activity?

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

Intent update = new Intent(context, IntervalService.class);
 context.stopService(update);

Comment: I use it but don't stop InternalService class.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to cancel the Service not the alarm manager

If a component starts the service by calling startService() (which results in a call to onStartCommand()), then the service remains running until it stops itself with stopSelf() or another component stops it by calling stopService().

Refrence : http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html